# is it possible to cast Button to TextView?

Tags: android, android-view, textview, android-button

I had two Button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/fragment_remote_control_zeroButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="0" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/fragment_remote_control_oneButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="1" />
```

And there is a listener for both of them:

```
View.OnClickListener numberButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
      TextView textView = (TextView)v;
      String working = mWorkingTextView.getText().toString();
      String text = textView.getText().toString();
      if (working.equals("0")) {
         mWorkingTextView.setText(text);
      } else {
           mWorkingTextView.setText(working + text);
    }
  }
};
```

in listener's `onClick(View v)`method, the method parameter is `The view that was clicked`, that here is the clicked Button
but i'm wonder how it cast a Button to a TextView???is that refer to the text value in Button or not???

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @UdiI there are two TextView, one is for when i click one two above Button its value appear in one of them, and then if i press enter the value go to the other TextView, and if press Delete then reset the first TextView

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand exactly what you mean. If you can explain a bit more, I will try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Button is actually a subclass of TextView

However, the code is definitely strange, in order to identify which button is clicked, you can check the id
e.g.

```
  if (v.getId() == R.id.fragment_remote_control_zeroButton) {
     mWorkingTextView.setText(text);
  } else {
       mWorkingTextView.setText(working + text);
  }
```

Comment: i set listener for both of them separately with setOnClickListener bbut did not show here, and my main problem was about casting a Button to TextView

Comment: So I have told you, Button is a subclass of TextView, so the `View v` received is a Button, and thus is a TextView, so, it is fine

Comment: Just like TextView is a View, Button is actually a TextView in android

Comment: and here `String text = textView.getText().toString();` what value text variable would take??? the `android:text=` value???